# What could an attacker do with informations about devices in my local network?

Tags: network, network-scanners, webrtc

If a malicious website would scan my local network (via WebRTC) for devices, what could the attacker do it with it?
Does it need to be in the same WIFI-Network in order to login to a service? (for example a web based interface to configure your IP home-phone)

I'm asking because I came across this website today: http://webkay.robinlinus.com/
The "Network Scan" feature lets you are scan for devices in your local network. (Worked for me in the latest Google Chrome)

Answer (score 2):

Just a few examples:

- Detect the type of router and exploit it via CSRF. Then change the DNS settings and thus have man in the middle attack. See [this example where millions of DSL routers got hacked](https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2012/10/01/hacked-routers-brazil-vb2012/).
- Use CSRF, XSS, DNS rebinding etc to extract information from internal web sites, i.e. internal web mail, company wiki etc.
- Use the web interface of VoIP phones to make expensive calls or switch on the microphone and listen to whatever happens in the room.
- Just collect various information which then help to attack specific targets (i.e. intelligence).